# Php multiple array values to single array

Tags: php, wordpress

For example

`[Nationality_1] string(8)=>Indian [Nationality_5] string(12)=>American [Nationality_12] string(17)=>Japanese`

I got these array values by foreach loop but I want to put these value to single array by index on strings

Desired output
`[Nationality] [0] string(8)=>Indian [1] string(12)=>American[2]string(17)=>Japanese`

I have tried `array_values` but output Null

I tried this but creates duplicate array in loop for multiple orders Please help me on it . Thanks
`$Nationality[] = $value;`

Comment: your question is not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is below code:

```
$nationality = array(
    'Nationality_1' => 'Indian',
    'Nationality_2' => 'American',
    'Nationality_3' => 'Japanese'
);
$temp = array();
foreach ($nationality as $val) {
    $temp[] = $val;
}
$nationality = $temp;
print_r($nationality);
unset($temp);
// Array ( [0] => Indian [1] => American [2] => Japanese )
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may want to use `array_values` to pull all the nationalities from your input list.

> **array_values**
>
> Return all the values of an array
>
> http://php.net/array_values

What you do with that is then up to you but from your desired output it seems you want them under another array with a "Nationality" key?

Here is an example...

```
$input = array(
    'Nationality_1' => 'Indian',
    'Nationality_5' => 'American',
    'Nationality_12' => 'Japanese'
);

$output = array('Nationality' => array_values($input));

var_dump($output);

/*
array(1) {
  ["Nationality"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "Indian"
    [1]=>
    string(8) "American"
    [2]=>
    string(8) "Japanese"
  }
}
*/
```

See the code in action: https://eval.in/869938